# How to run this bash file on Docker?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, yocto

I have a Yocto project and a bash file below. I don't know how to build that Yocto project using the bash file below on Docker.

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run --rm \
    -v /opt/yocto/3_0/downloads:/opt/yocto/3_0/downloads \
    -v $(pwd):/workdir \
    -e YOCTO_DOWNLOAD_DIR=/opt/yocto/3_0/downloads \
    -e YOCTO_WORKING_DIR=/workdir \
    -e YOCTO_IMX_BRANCH=imx-linux-kirkstone \
    -e YOCTO_IMX_MANIFEST=imx-5.15.71-2.2.0.xml \
    -e YOCTO_IMX_MACHINE=imx6ull9x9mobizv2 \
    -e YOCTO_IMX_DISTRO=mobiz-tiny \
    -e CUSTOM_LAYERS="meta-mobiz,meta-murata-wireless" \
    -e MAKE_THREADS=12 \
    -it advinno/yocto-imx-builder bash
```

Comment: Did you make that file executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You, literally, have a bash script, just run it.

Maybe you need to make sure that you have `/opt/yocto/3_0/downloads` in your machine.

It seems that what ever directory containing the bash script will be used as the working directory, the following is not a reference, but something for you to understand:

```
mkdir -p /opt/yocto/3_0/downloads
mkdir workdir
cd workdir
vim build.sh       # Copy that content here
chmod u+x build.sh
./build.sh
```